# Solve this system of trigonometric equations

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

How to solve this system of equations analytically?

$$
\begin{cases}
\:9\tan\alpha -\frac{4.9\cdot 9^2}{v^2\cos^2\alpha }=2.1\\
\:23\tan\alpha \:-\frac{4.9\cdot \:23^2}{v^2\cos^2\alpha \:}=2.44
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the catch! Is the procedure clear now? Or is any clarification needed?

Comment: @KM101 Thanks, now everything is clear!

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x = v^2\cos^2\alpha$ and $y = \tan\alpha$.

For the first equation:

$$9y-\frac{4.9(9^2)}{x} = 2.1 \implies 9xy-396.9 = 2.1x \implies 9xy-2.1x = 396.9$$

$$\implies x(9y-2.1) = 396.9 \implies \color{blue}{x = \frac{396.9}{9y-2.1}}\tag{1}$$

For the second equation:

$$23y-\frac{4.9(23^2)}{x} = 2.44 \implies 23xy-2592.1 = 2.44x \implies 23xy-2.44u = 2592.1$$

$$x(23y-2.44) = 2592.1 \implies \color{green}{x = \frac{2592.1}{23y-2.44}}\tag{2}$$

So now, you have equations $(1)$ and $(2)$.

$$\color{blue}{x} = \color{green}{x}$$

$$\implies \frac{396.9}{9y-2.1} = \frac{2592.1}{23y-2.44}$$

Solve for $y$, obtain $\alpha$, solve for $x$, then plug $\alpha$ in $x = v^2\cos^2a$ to get $v$.